# How to retrieve hierarchical tree structure data from database using hibernate and java?

Tags: java, hibernate, tree

i want to create categories section for my website and wants to do it using hibernate and core java. Data pattern in database will be like this:

```
*category-id*   *name*     *parent_id*
1               Movies         0
2               hollywood      1
3               tv series      0
4               bollywood      1
5               action         2
6               drama          2
7               action         4
```

and i want data as

```
movies
 -hollywood
   -action
   -drama
 -bollywood
   -action
tv series
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You do it exactly like you would do it *without* using Hibernate. Use a `Set` to store children and a plain old reference for parent. Then when you create your Hibernate entity mappings, just use standard bidirectional one-to-many (parent-to-child) mappings (from the entity class to itself). (By the way, `null` instead of `0` for root element parent IDs will end up being easier to work with.) What have you attempted so far and what problems are you having?

Comment: Jason..i am a new in programming and i was just trying to retrieve data but i did not got idea to retrieve it using recursion method.